# Validate multiple selectors on click and unclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery(function($){

    var nickname = $('#nickname');
    var email = $('#email');
    var email_match = $('#email_match');
    var password = $('#password');
    var birthday_day = $('#birthday_day');
    var birthday_month = $('#birthday_month');
    var birthday_year = $('#birthday_year');
    var gender_femal = $('#gender_female');
    var gender_femal = $('#gender_male');

    var error = $('.error');

    nickname.blur( function(){
        if (nickname.val() < 1) error.html('error')
    });
    nickname.click( function(){
        if (nickname.val() > 0) error.html('')
    });
});
```

Now this only works for nickname selector what is the easiest way to check all selectors without copy paste the same function.

for example

`blur/focus(function(){if (nickname || email || password < 0) error.html('error'); });`

while i'm typing this question i'm getting the idea that the best way is to duplicate the function this because i want to show error if the value is empty.

But i like to hear from the pro's i believe there will be a good way to do this.

Comment: why u are using nickname.val() < 1 , is nickname return numeric value ? why not check  nickname.val()  != '' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target them all in one selector, like so:

```
var fields = $('#nickname, #email, #password, ...');
```

But it might be easier if you can identify them with something common like:

```
var fields = $('#some-container :input');
```

...or:

```
var fields = $('.form-fields');
```

Once you have by some means identified a set of all the elements of interest, you may bind the event handlers to all of them at once:

```
fields.blur(function() {
   // 'this' will refer to the DOM node blurred, even though fields refers to all of them
   var field = $(this);
   if(field.val().length == 0)
      error.html('error');
});
```

Comment: Great answer THANKS! I'm using the third example now i needed to add .form-fields inside the input area like class=form-fields. Now it works perfect thanks you very much!